# IBM Worklight V6 logout not working

Tags: console-application, ibm-mobilefirst, war

I have deployed a war file on the worklight server.  e.g. BPMWorklightV6.war.

I have used the ant script to deploy and the **//hostname:port/BPMWorklightV6/console** works.  It prompts for a login and will display the applications and adpaters that are installed.

When I click "logout" to logout of the console it  just redisplays the console page.

Comment: Please add some more information, like your Worklight version, what is this BMPWorklight project (where did you get it from?), what do you use for the login, where did you set it up, how did you set it up. Which documentation topic did you follow?

Comment: Worklight V6.1.  The BPMWorklight project is a POC from IBM. We use Active Directory to authenticate a user.  The documentation link is as follows:  http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc%2Fdeploy%2Fc_deploy_wl_project.html&resultof%3D%2522%2577%2561%2572%2522%2520

Answer (score 0):

By default your worklight console will be logged in as Guest. So only when you click logout nothing happening.
However you can protect the worklight console by setting user name and password ( both plain text and encrypted format is possible ). Refer [this](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.help.doc%2Fwl_home.html) for more info to protect your worklight console.

Comment: We do protect the login by using Active Directory to authenticate the user.  This technique works fine with the worklight console.  It also works for the WAR file console.  It's the logout that doesn't work on the WAR file console.  It works just fine for the worklight console.

Comment: @wallyjava What do you mean by WAR Console?Are you protecting your App with active directory or the worklight console? You are deploying WAR file into server by using Ant script and it can be accessed via `http://hostname:port/contextroot/console`.

Comment: Yes, the WAR console.  The worklight console is protected using active directory.  The WAR file console is not.  Yes, I am deploying the WAR file into the server using the Ant script and it can be accessed by the URL you have listed.

Comment: @wallyjava Please share your authenticationConfig.xml

Comment: just a doubt. Where did you mention the security test for protecting the worklight console? I hope it is suthenticationConfi.xml and not application-descriptor.xml